# How to cast the screen of android device with chromecast?

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

I'm developing an app which casts a screen of android device with Chromecast. but, I don't know how to cast the screen to a monitor.

How does Chromecast App cast the screen to a monitor?

Comment: Are you looking for this? https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/remote

Comment: @LynnCrumbling Thank you. but, it's not what I'm looking for. That page describe only how to send a custom layout.

Answer (score 0):

Please note, the following way requires the Chromecast app running on Android 4.4.2 or greater.

Check this
https://support.google.com/chromecast/answer/6059461?hl=en